# Trying to alloc more than 2GB on a windows 7

Tags: c++, memory, runtime

I'm usining Windows 7, 64bits, 8GB ram
I'm needing to make alloc more than 2GB but I'm getting runtime error

look at my piece of code

```
#define MAX_PESSOAS 30000000

int i;
double ** totalPessoas = new double *[MAX_PESSOAS];
for(i = 0; i < MAX_PESSOAS; i++)
    totalPessoas[i] = new double [5];
```

MAX_PESSOAS is set to 30milion, but I'll need at least 1billion (ok, I know I'll need more than 8GB but nvm, I can get it, I only need to know how to do that )

I'm using visual studio 2012

Comment: Is your process 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: You don't need more than 8GB RAM. You need to understand *Virtual Memory*.

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 has a fine debugger. Go do *Debug* -> *Exceptions...* and tick the *Thrown* checkbox next to *C++ Exceptions*. Run the code under the debugger and the application will break into the debugger when the `std::bad_alloc` is thrown, giving you all the information you need.

Answer (score 3):

If your application is building to a 64-bit binary, it can address more than 8 GB without any special steps.
If your application is building to a 32-bit binary, you can address up to 3 GB (or 4 GB if you're running 64-bit Windows) by enabling [4-gigabyte tuning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb613473%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), as long as the system supports it.

Your best bet is probably to compile your application as a 64-bit binary, if you know that the operating system it will be running on is 64-bit.

Comment: If you run a 32-bit application on a 64-bit version of Windows your application will have the full 4GB of address space available, if the  IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE flag is set in the linker (also required for the /3GB boot switch).

Comment: Thanks, I had forgotten about that!

Comment: Is it possible to use more than 3GB ? then where is kernel space ?

Comment: @magingax: Kernel space memory is separate from user space memory. You could have the address 0x12345678, and it would map to two different pages, depending on whether it's accessed from kernel space or user space.

Comment: I must have write my question more detail. In normal 32bit application. 2GB (user space) + 2GB (kernel space) = 4GB ..But wonder. in Wow64 situation (run 32bit application on 64bit os) everybody just say 4GB can be used for user space. then Where is kernel space for that situation ?